# java unit test input exceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mocking

I have the method which scans the input from console:

```
private int chooseItem() throws IOException {
    return inputoutput.inputValue();
}

public int inputValue() throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
```

As you can see it expects to get `int` as incoming value and if I enter `String`, it should throw `InputMismatchEcxeption`. The question is how in Java I can teach inputValue to return smth not int, for example, string and check the fact that the exception was throwed? In other words to test it?
I tried:

```
IO io = mock(IO.class); 

when(io.inputValue()).thenReturn("fdas");
```

But mockito just says that io.inputValue can not return string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simulate an input from your test, you can do something like this.

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( "fdas".getBytes() );
System.setIn(inputStream);
```

and in the `inputStream` object you can make it pass a String instead of int.

Comment: How can I put two values under inputStream? Like "fdas" and next time 0? it turned out throwing exception inside my program does not stop the program.

Comment: @ovod Since you're trying to test two different behaviors, you should separate that in to two test methods and each test method should create its own `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the `System.in` to an input stream to read the invalid input:

```
InputStream in = System.in;
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("fdas".getBytes()));
try {
    // call inputValue method
} finally {
    System.setIn(in);  // restore old input stream
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I know that))) The question is I can not really give string to inputValue since I can not test it via console. I need somethow to command inputValue to return not int but something wrong to test exception.

Comment: Ah I see... Then I think you may have to change the input stream to read from some other stream.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use Mockitos thenThrow option to make the InputMisMatchException be always thrown. You can then test your handling of it in your own code via some method.

```
when(io.inputValue()).thenThrow(new InputMismatchException());
```